# IIS 8 Windows authentication

Tags: authentication, iis

I am facing a problem in IIS8 The all Url's is running normal but one of them is not (domain/reports) is asking for prompt username and password, the IIS authentication anonymous is enabled and windows is disabled.

I do not know why for that links is asking for windows authentication.

Comment: Any 401 return code will trigger the prompt, no matter what sub status is. Analyze IIS log file to learn the sub status and use failed request tracing to learn which module returns it.